# Why multiprocess pool map does not work like map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I try to parallelize grouping of a list of letters. The two functions below seem identical, one sequential and the other multiprocessed. However results are not same.

```
from itertools import groupby, count
import random
from multiprocess import Pool

random.seed(0)

input_letter = ["a", "b", "c"]

a = [random.choice(input_letter) for _ in range(10)]
print("input a", a)

def functional_map_approach(a:list) -> list:
    def reducer(x): 
        return [v for v, _ in x[1]]  
    
    return list(map(reducer, groupby(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])))

def functional_multiprocess_approach(a:list) -> list:        
    def reducer(x): 
        return [v for v, _ in x[1]]
    
    with Pool(5) as p:
        res= p.map(reducer, groupby(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1]))
    return res
        

assert functional_map_approach(a) == functional_multiprocess_approach(a), (functional_map_approach(a), functional_multiprocess_approach(a))
```

Output:

```
input a ['b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']

AssertionError: ([[0, 1], [2], [3], [4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[], [], [], [], []])
```

Could someone help me understand why results are different and what is the correct code to parallelize the computation?

Comment: When I run your code I get `Traceback (most recent call last): File "Untitled2.py", line 3, in <module>from multiprocess import Pool ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocess'`
Did you mean `multiprocessing` instead of `multiprocess`?

Comment: I use multiprocess instead of multiprocessing. First uses `dill` as serialized and second uses `pickle`. Dill covers more problems, especially when you get an error with serializing. https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/ - this library

Comment: multiprocessing fails with this error `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'functional_multiprocess_approach.<locals>.reducer'`

Comment: I found that. To understand your code better what does this do: `functional_multiprocess_approach(a), (functional_map_approach(a), functional_multiprocess_approach(a))`

Comment: What you are referring to is part of assert statement. Left side is the comparison and right side is what should be the output if comparison fails

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don’t use assert much even though I probably should

Comment: If you are running on Windows, `reducer` needs to be defined at global scope.

Comment: I'm running on Mac

Comment: Let me re-phrase: If you are running on a platform that uses the *spawn* method to create new processes, then `reducer` needs to be at global scope. That would be, for example, Windows and more recently Mac (it used to use the *fork* method by default, but now uses *spawn* by default, I believe).

Comment: I took out reducer, and put to global space. It doesn't change the result. And I don't understand why it would. My code is easy to run. If you know how to solve the problem why don't you just write an answer with your code so that everyone can try it.